# Drupal 6: View module generates div mess :/

Tags: drupal, html, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I created some blocks with View Module. View Module really makes things easy! but it puts so many divs, class-names, etc... to output. and it mess up for some cases. example below:

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100630-kh7rtfgj987c3dieibxu7wdxyd.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100630-kh7rtfgj987c3dieibxu7wdxyd.jpg)

How can I get a CLEAN output from view? without any div, span...

Appreciate helps! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own [theme files](http://drupal.org/node/221881) for the views to over ride the default output. If you click on 'theme information' in your views admin it will show you the candidate template files used.

However having a lot of divs won't hurt necessarily, so approach re theming with caution.

Comment: woa life saver you are!! your tip and the tutorial at the link http://www.templatezine.com/2010/03/views-styles-and-theming-how-to-redefine-html-output/ now View Module has no limits for me ;) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can also try [Semantic Views](http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews).

Comment: woa that's so cool! I just made the work in 2 mins that I have spend over a day! Thanks a lot for the link! Appreciate

Answer (score 2):

Try Style=unformatted in the basic settings (as opposed to Grid or Table or Panel etc).

Comment: Nice easy option, didn't think of that.